# Trying to find the user's remote IP-address

Tags: asp.net, ip

I'm working on an ASP.NET project that needs to find the user's remote IP-address. I've searched around and I've found this:

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

The problem is that it only returns "::1" and not the IP-address. Can it be that the problem occurs because I use a local server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because you are using a local server.

The address `"::1"` is the IPv6 address for `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bulletproof way of getting user IP address, as there might be a lot of proxy servers along the way. The result you are receiving is correct for localhost, but `REMOTE_ADDR` will return the last proxy on the list if the client comes from outside. There is a list of HTTP headers which might contain the actual IP address but those can be forged as well. You can read following blog post for more details (you shold also read the comments):

- [Attempting to retrieve a user's real IP address](http://tpeczek.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/attempting-to-retrieve-user-real-ip.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Net;
string host = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);
Console.WriteLine(ip.AddressList[1].ToString());
```